# Can't revert a "replaced" action

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using TortoiseSVN version 1.8.  A few revisions ago, I reintegrated a branch that caused some files to be replaced in trunk*.  I reverted the revision and re-merged, being careful to revert the replaced files in my working copy before committing.

However, now I see that those files are still marked as Replaced in trunk.  When I merged from trunk to a different branch, it tries to replace those files.

I noticed that the revision that reverted the bad merge to trunk reverted everything but the replaced files.  Now, when I go to that revision, select one of the replaced files and choose "Revert Changes from This Revision", it seems to do something, but my working copy remains unchanged.  Even when I select the revision before the merge and choose "Revert To This Revision" for the whole trunk, it does nothing to the replaced files.

I am at a loss as to how to revert the "Replace" action on those files.

*I think this was because at some point, a merge from trunk to branch happened wrong. The files might have been added to the branch without knowing that they came from trunk, so when they were reintegrated, they replaced the original files.

Answer (score 6):

Partial solution:

I managed to manually get the history back for the replaced files, although I do have to uncheck the "Stop on Copy/Rename" box to see all of it.  I svn-deleted the replaced files in a working copy of the latest trunk, opened the repo-browser from before the bad merge, selected the files and chose "Copy to working copy...".  I committed and now the files have access to their history again, but it still sees them as having been deleted and re-added.

Answer (score 0):

The only way for me to fix this was (on svn trunk) to 
- create a tag based on the revision before the commit which included the replace that I wanted to revert
- rename the trunk to trunk2
- copy the previously created tag to the trunk
- asked everybody to recheckout the trunk

Answer (score -1):

go to tortoise, get the history of the trunk, select the 'bad' revision, right click and choose "revert this revision". This will revert all changes that were made in that revision to your working copy. You can then check it in and the rev will be effectively deleted.

Alternatively, choose a revision you know is good, click it and select "revert to this revision" which will undo all changes since then.

Important: You're best off with a fresh, clean, newly checked out working copy, mainly so you know exactly what the state of things are that you're working with.

Comment: I tried both of those, and it worked on everything except the replaced files.  Even though it shows that the files were replaced, reverting the revision (or reverting to a revision before it) does not affect the replaced files.